# POST archivo .txt usando lib. "requests" - Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, nodejs, post, python-requests

Estoy intentando transformar un script de nodeJS a Python. El script manda un archivo .txt a un servidor, luego dicho servidor contiene un microservicio encargado de transformar los datos y los inserta a una base de datos.

La parte del script encargada del envío (en javascript) es:

```
const url = `${proto}://${host}/api/lecture/file`;
 console.log('Posting to:', url);
  const stream = createReadStream(qsFileName);
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('files', stream);
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: form,
  });
  console.log('Status:', res.status);
  console.log('Response:\n\n', await res.json());
};
```

Estoy intentando emular esto en python usando la libreria "requests" de la siguiente manera:

```
import requests

fileName = 'ejemplo.txt'
url = 'https://hostname.com/api/lecture/file'
file = open('fileName', 'rb')
req = requests.post(url, data= file)
print(req.status_code)
```

El código de respuesta del requests es 404.

No se si es debido a un problema del formato del data en el requests.post o si debería hacerlo de otra forma, de ser así espero alguien me pueda orientar.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar un archivo usando `requests` tienes que crear un diccionario
con los nombres de los archivos como llave y los archivos abiertos como el
valor asociado a esas llaves. Luego, se lo pasas a `requests.post` con el
parámetro `files`. Por ejemplo:

```
import requests

files = {"files": open("ejemplo.txt", "rb")}

respuesta = requests.post("http://localhost", files=files)

print(respuesta.status_code)
print(respuesta.text)
```

Comment: Solucionado! Gracias por la respuesta.